# NVIDIA graphics driver in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: drivers, installation, ubuntu-12.04, cuda

So my overall goal is that I want to be able to code with CUDA enabled applications.
However, upon many days of searching, using installation walkthroughs, and reinstalling countless times after driver failure... I'm now here as a last resort.

I cannot get Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to install the NVIDIA 295.59 driver for my GeForce GT 540M NVIDIA graphics card.

My main system specs is as follows...  (I believe having the Intel processor may be the problem)

DELL Laptop XPS L502X
Intel® Core™ i7-2620M CPU @ 2.70GHz × 4
    Intel Integrated Graphics
64 bit
NVIDIA GeForce GT 540M
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
All other specs are irrelevant unless I forgot something?

Methods Tried:
aptitude install nvidia-current (all packages)

Results:
Nothing really happened.  Nothing in the additional drivers menu appeared, nor was the NVIDIA X Server settings application allowing access because it thought there was no NVIDIA X Server installed.

---

Downloaded driver from nvidia.com.
Set nomodeset in the grub boot menu through /boot/grub/grub.cfg
Went to console and turned off lightdm.
Installed the driver, but it said the pre-install failed? (mean anything?)
Started up lightdm again.

Results:
NVIDIA X Server settings still didn't notice it.  Even tried to do nvidia-xconfig multiple times.  I also went into the config file to make sure the driver setting said "nvidia".

---

aptitude install nvidia-173 (all packages)

Results:
Couldn't find the xorg-video-abi-10 virtual package.  It was nowhere to be found and the ubuntu forums everywhere had no answers.  Lots of people were having this problem.

---

This is easily done in windows, simply download the driver and debug in visual studio with no problems at all. I'd like clear step-by-step instructions on how I should go about this.  I'm relatively new to linux but I can find my way around pretty well so you aren't talking to a straight-up beginner.  Also, if you think another thread may have the answer please post because I was having a hard time looking for my specific type of problem.

TL;DR  I want to have access to my GPU so I can code with CUDA while in Ubuntu 12.04 on my 64 bit laptop that also has Intel integrated graphics on the processor.

Solution:
     sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install nvidia-current

Comment: This is not an answer but thought of posting anyways : http://www.tubechop.com/watch/404677

Comment: @EswarRajeshPinapala Try my answer. Let me know if it helps!

Comment: offering a port to [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com/). this question might be a better fit down there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is there any specific reason you want version 295.59 installed?

**Solution I (Preferred)**

I would recommend looking at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qYYnTdX6EwI.

I quote from the link Description (Credit: Youtube User: LastAxis)

```
"#CUDA:
http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads
#Normal:
http://www.geforce.co.uk/drivers

First install the following libraries & Tools:
sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev build-essential libx11-dev libxmu-dev libxi-dev libgl1-mesa-glx libglu1-mesa libglu1-mesa-dev

Next we will blacklist some modules(drivers), in terminal enter:
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

Add the following to the end of the file(one per line like so):
blacklist amd76x_edac
blacklist vga16fb
blacklist nouveau
blacklist rivafb
blacklist nvidiafb
blacklist rivatv

Save the file and close the editor.
Now we want to get rid of any nvidia risiduals, in terminal:
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*

Next you need to restart your machine (sudo reboot).

# Please DON'T do the next step until you have watched the video! #

0) Press Ctrl+Alt+F1 at login screen(you don't have to login, we'll have to restart later anyway), then log in.
1) sudo service lightdm stop
2) cd Downloads
3) chmod +x devdriver*.run (your driver filename)
4) sudo ./devdriver*.run

You might have to run the driver-installer once, reboot(it will remove nouveau drivers) and repeat the steps again. Follow the installer instructions and it will be fine, when it asks you;
yes, you do want the 32-bit libraries and you DO want it to change the xorg.conf file.

Once the installer completes, restart (sudo reboot). You're done :]"
```

**Solution II**

If the solution in the link did not work for you then first uninstall nvidia drivers (if any) then use the following procedure (before reinstalling again).

```
sudo apt-get autoremove nvidia-*
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.orig1
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Go to "Dash Home" (top left) and type "system settings"> "Hardware" > "Additional Drivers". Ensure nothing is active (may have to restart PC if the message instructs accordingly.).

Installing NVIDIA drivers (295.49 is Stable as of now although a new 295.53 is available)

*- Ubuntu 32-bit (i386):*

```
cd ~/; mkdir nvidia295.49; cd nvidia295.49/
wget -O NVIDIA-Linux-x86-295.49.run http://goo.gl/1f9kc
chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86-295.49.run

Ctrl+Alt+F1

login with user/password

then

sudo service lightdm stop
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86-295.49.run (follow instructions)
sudo reboot
```

*- Ubuntu 64-bit (amd64):*

```
cd ~/; mkdir nvidia295.49; cd nvidia295.49/
wget -O NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-295.49.run http://goo.gl/hg4Kz
chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-295.49.run

Ctrl+Alt+F1

login with user/password

then

sudo service lightdm stop
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86-295.49.run (follow instructions)
sudo reboot
```

If you screw anything simply restore the original `sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf.orig /etc/X11/xorg.conf` (or remove this if using Onchip Intel Card)

**Alternative**

**WORST CASE ALTERNATIVE: *FOR OPENGL ONLY (WITHOUT CUDA)***

Try the following on Ubuntu 12.04 **[Worst case if nothing works with NVIDIA GPU, with this you can use OpenGL with Intel onchip display card if not for NVIDIA's CUDA Kit]**

```
glxinfo
```

If it says something like

```
name of display: :0.0
Xlib: extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib: extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib: extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib: extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib: extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig

Xlib: extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib: extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib: extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib: extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib: extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib: extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib: extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
```

Then proceed

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.orig
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

For 32 bit Reinstall xorg completely

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
```

For 64 bit Reinstall xorg completely

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64
```

The OS info (32 bit/64 bit) can be verified using `uname -a`

Then Reconfigure Xorg

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
sudo reboot
```

On reboot run `glxinfo` again and verify that those values

```
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGIS_multisample, 
    GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, 
    GLX_INTEL_swap_event
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_swap_control, 
    GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync, GLX_SGIS_multisample, 
    GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, 
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_INTEL_swap_event
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_swap_control, 
    GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync, GLX_SGIS_multisample, 
    GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, 
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap
OpenGL vendor string: Tungsten Graphics, Inc
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 8.1-devel
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL extensions:
    GL_ARB_multisample, GL_EXT_abgr, GL_EXT_bgra, GL_EXT_blend_color, 
    GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_blend_subtract, GL_EXT_copy_texture, 
    GL_EXT_polygon_offset, GL_EXT_subtexture, GL_EXT_texture_object, 
    GL_EXT_vertex_array, GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array, GL_EXT_texture, 
    GL_EXT_texture3D, GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip, GL_ARB_point_parameters, 
    GL_EXT_draw_range_elements, GL_EXT_packed_pixels, GL_EXT_point_parameters, 
    GL_EXT_rescale_normal, GL_EXT_separate_specular_color, 
    GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp, GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap, 
    GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp, GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp, 
    GL_SGIS_texture_lod, GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_ARB_multitexture, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays, 
    GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1, 
    GL_ARB_texture_cube_map, GL_ARB_texture_env_add, GL_ARB_transpose_matrix, 
    GL_EXT_blend_func_separate, GL_EXT_fog_coord, GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, 
    GL_EXT_secondary_color, GL_EXT_texture_env_add, 
    GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias, 
    GL_INGR_blend_func_separate, GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_light_max_exponent, 
    GL_NV_texgen_reflection, GL_NV_texture_env_combine4, GL_S3_s3tc, 
    GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays, GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp, 
    GL_ARB_texture_compression, GL_EXT_framebuffer_object, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc, GL_EXT_texture_env_combine, 
    GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3, GL_MESA_window_pos, GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil, 
    GL_NV_texture_rectangle, GL_NV_vertex_program, GL_ARB_depth_texture, 
    GL_ARB_occlusion_query, GL_ARB_shadow, GL_ARB_texture_env_combine, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar, GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3, 
    GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_ARB_window_pos, GL_ATI_envmap_bumpmap, 
    GL_EXT_stencil_two_side, GL_EXT_texture_cube_map, GL_NV_depth_clamp, 
    GL_NV_vertex_program1_1, GL_APPLE_packed_pixels, 
    GL_APPLE_vertex_array_object, GL_ARB_draw_buffers, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_program, GL_ARB_fragment_shader, GL_ARB_shader_objects, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_program, GL_ARB_vertex_shader, GL_ATI_draw_buffers, 
    GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3, GL_ATI_texture_float, GL_EXT_shadow_funcs, 
    GL_EXT_stencil_wrap, GL_MESA_pack_invert, GL_MESA_ycbcr_texture, 
    GL_NV_primitive_restart, GL_ARB_depth_clamp, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow, GL_ARB_half_float_pixel, 
    GL_ARB_point_sprite, GL_ARB_shading_language_100, GL_ARB_sync, 
    GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object, 
    GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate, GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate, 
    GL_OES_read_format, GL_ARB_color_buffer_float, GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc, GL_ARB_texture_float, 
    GL_ARB_texture_rectangle, GL_EXT_packed_float, GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1, GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc, 
    GL_EXT_texture_rectangle, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB, 
    GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent, GL_ARB_framebuffer_object, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit, GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample, 
    GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil, GL_APPLE_object_purgeable, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_object, GL_ATI_separate_stencil, GL_EXT_draw_buffers2, 
    GL_EXT_draw_instanced, GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters, 
    GL_EXT_texture_array, GL_EXT_texture_integer, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode, 
    GL_EXT_timer_query, GL_OES_EGL_image, GL_MESA_texture_array, 
    GL_ARB_copy_buffer, GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float, GL_ARB_draw_instanced, 
    GL_ARB_half_float_vertex, GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, GL_ARB_texture_rg, 
    GL_ARB_texture_swizzle, GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra, 
    GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects, GL_EXT_texture_swizzle, 
    GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra, GL_NV_conditional_render, 
    GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend, GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility, 
    GL_ARB_blend_func_extended, GL_ARB_debug_output, 
    GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend, GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex, 
    GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location, GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions, 
    GL_ARB_provoking_vertex, GL_ARB_sampler_objects, GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map, 
    GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod, GL_EXT_provoking_vertex, GL_EXT_texture_snorm, 
    GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba, GL_ARB_robustness, GL_EXT_transform_feedback

32 GLX Visuals
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x021 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x022 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a3 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a4 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a5 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a6 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a7 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a8 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a9 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0aa 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0ab 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0ac 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0ad 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0ae 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0af 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b0 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0b1 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b2 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b3 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b4 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b5 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b6 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b7 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b8 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b9 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0ba 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0bb 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0bc 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0bd 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0be 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0bf 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x072 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None

48 GLXFBConfigs:
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x073  0 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x074  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x075  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x076  0 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x077  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x078  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x079 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07a 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07b 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07c 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07d 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07e 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07f 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x080 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x081 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x082 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x083 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x084 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x085  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x086  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x087 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x088 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x089 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x08a 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x08b  0 dc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x08c  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x08d  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x08e  0 dc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x08f  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x090  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x091 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x092 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x093 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x094 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x095 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x096 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x097 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x098 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x099 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x09a 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x09b 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x09c 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x09d  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x09e  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x09f 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a0 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0a1 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a2 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
```

verify that system is using intel graphics driver `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log`

**UPDATE:**

It appears Bumblebee Drivers is the only choice at this juncture for NVIDIA Optimus technology loaded GPU.

Comment: This is very helpful.  Thank you enthusiasticgeek.  However, since I forgot to mention that my computer is not only on hybrid graphics but the NVIDIA card is Optimus loaded, this invariably does not work.  Therefore, I have finally found my solution with Bumblebee.

Comment: Oh yeah sure I should have listed it too. I found some info and yes you are correct with a very limited choice for NVIDIA OPTIMUS http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Optimus. At this juncture Bumblebee drivers is your only choice! I wish NVIDIA extends better open source support :)

Answer (score -1):

There is a display driver available for download at Nvidia's site [here](http://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/52241). It supports your graphics card (the GeForce GT 540M), and CUA.

Check it out, it may help you (I've had this same issue)!

Comment: Also, Espadas, keep in mind that I am working with Optimus technology so for now just the driver doesn't help out.  Bumblebee is the best option for now.